# Most promising QML algorithms in the NISQ era

Tags: quantum-advantage, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

This question was asked in the previous years, but how is 2023 state of the art Quantum Machine Learning ?

Things seem to go fast in this area, for instance I saw Thales used 4 qubits for quantum reinforcement learnign this month : https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.07181.pdf

What are the most promising QML algorithms today for the NISQ era ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'most promising' here? Most likely to be successfully run on a NISQ computer? Most likely to outperform a classical algorithm? Most likely to be a 'useful' application (in which case, what is 'useful' to you)?

Comment: Most likely to show quantum advantage